# Is it able to use AjaxPanel in this way?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a simple html table tag with 2x2 cells on my ascx.
There are two textbox control inside.
I wrapped the table by a ajaxPanel.

Outside the ajaxPanel, I have a button, and onclick event will set the value of two textbox to "1".

But after click the button, I found the value is set with postback.

Please advice~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will work without having the button inside the update panel:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Text1:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Text2:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `<Triggers>` in your html/aspx file.

Go there for more information: [Asp.net updatepanel overview](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should place your button inside the update panel as well.

Answer (score 0):

Place the button inside the update panel, or add the button as async postback trigger to the update panel, change the update mode of the panel to Conditional.